# time-in-mailbox metrics in grafana

Tags: metrics, units-of-measurement, grafana

I'm working with grafana in a scala project and I get metrics like processing-time with a value of 141.2K.
Somebody knows in which units are expressed the grafana metrics, for example mailbox-size, time-in-mailbox and processing-time?

Answer (score -1):

The unit of a metric is decided by the person sending the metric. Grafana does not demand a metric to have a unit. All grafana does is show you the metric stored in some database.

Ask the person who wrote the metric storing code to explain the unit for each metric.